# Scrolling is not working properly in IOS appium

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, appium

Scrolling is not working properly in IOS appium..Below code scrolls a bit but gets stopped in between and does not reach on bottom of the page.

I used below code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap(); 
scrollObject.put("direction", "up"); 
scrollObject.put("xpath", "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name=\"NAME\"]");
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);
```

Comment: It only swipes once. You have to repeat the swiping in a loop to simulate what a user does.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to scroll a few times to reach the end. A potential solution is :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap(); 
scrollObject.put("direction", "up"); 
scrollObject.put("xpath", "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name=\"NAME\"]");
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
    js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);
}
```

This script will swipe 10 times. You could make it more flexible by knowing how many times exactly you need to swipe.